# c out tag escapeXml not working when its value is fetched from the Spring Model

Tags: html, spring-mvc, jsp, taglib

I have an application that uses Spring MVC, before sending the response to the view (JSP) it adds an item to the spring model (org.springframework.ui.ModelMap), let's say the name of that item is element1 and the value is: `<b>This</b> is an <br/> example`

In the JSP, using a) and b) produce different results

a) <c:out value="${'`<b>This</b> is an <br/> example`'}" escapeXml="false"/>

b) <c:out value="${element1}" escapeXml="false"/>

a) produces

[image]

b) produces

[image]

I have been wrapping my head around this, I do not see any difference, except that b) uses a variable and a) uses the value but in both cases I am using the same tag (c:out) with the same value for the escapeXml attribute (false).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the value of variable element1 is `"<b>This</b> is an <br/> example"`?

Comment: @xdhmoore Yes, in both cases the value is the same in one case I am using the value and in another case I am using a variable and produces different results.

Comment: What is the type of the element1 variable?

Comment: It is a string.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://pukkaone.github.io/2011/01/03/jsp-cross-site-scripting-elresolver.html) where someone adds a custom jsp EL resolver I believe to get that behavior, but Idk if that's relevant to you.